# Rails form - Only submit the visible element (2x element with same id)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i got this:

A form with 2 select fields, both of them have the same id. I want that only the visible one gets submitted. Is there an solution for? Like adding an attribute to the element so that rails know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate id on same page is very bad practice. I suggest you to change them to unique ids instead of hacking a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just put invisible element before visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the one you don't want to submit `disabled` as well as hidden.

```
<input type="select" disabled="disabled" />
<!-- or.. -->
<%= select_tag :bla, disabled: true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :class attribute and then check which field is active with javascript.